# How to remove unnecessary margin on top?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for some work and I have successfully made the background for the headers and all. But the problem is, I want to join it to the top of my webpage but it refuses to do that. How do I prevent it? **(Not a duplicate of where the answer was adding `!Important` to the code)**

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html class="html">
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
 <title>LMUN - Home</title>
 <div class="header"></div>
 </head>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
 .html
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.header
{
    background-color: #70A5DA;
    height: 4.5%;
    width: 90%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-top:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;

}
```

Note: I want to keep position absolute as it allows me to set everything in percentage values which is very essential for me.

Comment: What does `position` have to do with setting something in percentages? You can always use percentages.

Comment: You can't place `div` elements inside of `head`.  `div` elements belong inside of the body.

Comment: @putvande No. In my DreamWeaver it doesn't show me the thing I did when I set it to other that fixed or absolute position.

Comment: @JamesMontagne How am I supposed to create header like on StackOverflow? It is in head, right?

Comment: No. It's in the body. The `head` tag is for meta tags, stylesheets, etc. Content (anything a user sees) goes in the body.

Comment: @4127157 `head` and "header" are two very different concepts.  From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.1) "The HEAD element contains information about the current document, such as its title, keywords that may be useful to search engines, and other data that is not considered document content. User agents do not generally render elements that appear in the HEAD as content"

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thank you. I encourage this to be voted down. Was dumb of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<title>LMUN - Home</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
}

.html
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.header
{
    background-color: #70A5DA;
    height: 4.5%;
    width: 90%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-top:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes for this you need to set the margin for body and also you can add same for html as 0.Then it will reduce unnecessary spaces. Like for example.

```
html{margin:0;}
body{margin:0}
```